# Can I turn updates on/off for one specific app in the Micorsoft Store?

Tags: updates, windows-store-app, windows-store, automatic-update

In the Microsoft Store, I have `Settings > App updates > Update apps automatically` turned on. But there's one app I'd like to only update manually. (Alternately, I could turn the global option off and turn all the other apps on manually.)

Is there a per-app update setting anywhere?

Comment: I presume you are not connected to a active directory domain

Comment: I am not. Just logged in to a MS account. PC on a workgroup.

Comment: Good question - Upvoted since I inadvertently rejected your edit on my answer a few minutes ago.  Please flag this as "no longer needed" when you see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a per-app update setting anywhere?

The only two options that exist, to handle updating installed UWP application, is to allow them to be automatically installed or manually update them.

The only exception to that statement is if you were connected to a domain, and the UWP applications that were installed, were being updated by an Administrator on the domain.  In that case, the Administration could choose which updates would be pushed out to specific applications, without being that person on the domain what you want isn’t possible.

You would have to be using Microsoft Store for Business or Microsoft Store for Education for this to work, and even then, you could only choose to update all of the installed applications automatically or manually install the updates to those applications.

Comment: So that's a no unless I'm on an AD domain and I'm the admin for that domain (and I wanted to get really hands-on about it).